# CocoaPods integration problems: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Bolts.framework/Bolts

Tags: parse-platform, swift2, cocoapods

I know that there are almost 1000 questions like this one, but I've tried all the answers on the others and no one could helps me.

I'm creating an app in Swift 2.0 that works with cocoapods. In my podfile I have:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'TargetName' do

pod 'SinchRTC'
pod 'SinchVerification-Swift'
pod 'Parse'

end
```

And everything was working fine, at one point I tried to run again the app and I got this error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Bolts.framework/Bolts
>    Referenced from:  ...
>   Reason: no suitable image found.
>   Did find: ... (lldb)

Then I tried everything like deleting and adding again pods, create a new project, deintegrate and reinstall cocoapods... 
Everytime I get the same error and if I remote Bolts.framework I get the error on another framework.
What should I do?

P.S. The app isn't running also in the simulator, not only on device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it! I tried everything but then I remember that the problem should also be the certificate signing my project and I run this lines in the terminal:

```
rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

This worked and the app is running right now on my device!

Comment: Where exactly does one do this? If I were to use this with another project name?

Comment: are these lines to be entered separately?

Comment: @skyguy you can also copy and paste them all together. I run them in the terminal, but not in a specific directory.