# Pods library not loaded in iOS multiple targets?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, bolts-framework

Ok, Ive never had this issue before, but having the same issue as this link I tried their solution: [CocoaPods integration problems: dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Bolts.framework/Bolts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860306/cocoapods-integration-problems-dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-bolts-framework)

But it did not work. I installed Parse via Pods and it runs but crashes shortly after with this Bolts error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Bolts.framework/Bolts
  Referenced from: /Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/67D47436-3F47-41E0-A6D6-FEE0DEB3447E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F54B120F-D1EE-496C-AC73-36D5B7561DD2/Anchorpoint.app/PlugIns/MessagesExtension.appex/MessagesExtension
  Reason: image not found
```

My pod file looks like - I followed directions on targeting multiple targets:

```
  # platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
    pod 'Parse'
end

target 'Anchorpoint' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Anchorpoint
    shared_pods
end

target 'MessagesExtension' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MessagesExtension
    shared_pods

end
```

its an iMessage extension, but I clearly target both the extension and the main target. This is crash is in ht simulator, and I have also tried going to Linked Libraries and adding Bolts there, and changing status to optional as someone suggested:

[image]

I don't know what else to do here. Why cant it find bolts?
EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Set  `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` to `YES` in targets build settings.

Comment: I tried that - see above

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: What else can I try? What is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34885710/1825618 ??

Comment: Yes but nothing happened - Im not versed in terminal are these lines to be entered separately?

Comment: Yes one by one .. and then try run pod install again for your project.

Comment: did not work, no.